# Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone in a CustomListAdapter causing unperdictable results

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, custom-lists

The use of CustomListAdapter to dynamically fill in a ListView isn't exactly overdocumented! It has been very difficult to find information on this, but I finally got it working.

Abstractly, in my listview CustomListAdapter, I populate a list showing a bunch of boxes and the contents of each. There are up to 4 items allowed (via LinearLayout of textViews) per box

```
Box 0
--------
shirts
shoes
ties
boxers

Box 1
-------
laptops

Box 2
-----
tennis racket
basketball
diving mask

Box 3
----------
tiles
grout
```

As long as I leave unused TextViews alone (i.e. blank & visible) the CustomListAdapter works fine. But the list gets very long with all of those blank lines displayed. In the LinearLayouts with < 4 items (such as Box 1), if I try to shrink the empty vertical space by setting the unused TextViews' visibility to "Gone", the data gets jumbled up in unpredictable ways, i.e. "diving mask" will appear in Box 1 instead of Box 2, and the contents of Box 0 will vanish.

Has anyone else experienced this unpredictability when using x.Visibility=ViewStates.Gone in a CustomListAdapter? Is there a better way than setting Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone to get rid of the vertical space occupied by the unused TextViews?

Comment: Sounds like a recycling issue. Post your adapter code.

Comment: "will appear in Box 1 instead of Box 2, and the contents of Box 0 will vanish" sounds to me like you are doing something else wrong. Where is the code that hides the TextViews - inside `getView`?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to remove the, item from the underlying last rather than hiding the ListView item?

Answer (score 1):

dmon, zapl, & Matthew:  Thanks for your replies. Here is some of the code from inside the GetView override function:

```
var  tv_class_title  =view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tv_class_title) as TextView;
var  tv_codex    =view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tv_codex) as TextView;

                //class title
if (item.class_title.Length>0){
  tv_class_title.SetText(item.class_title, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
}else{
  tv_class_title.Visibility     =       Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
}
                //codex
if (item.codex.Length>0){
  tv_codex.SetText(item.codex, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
}else{
  tv_codex.Visibility       =       Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
}                   

return view;
```

I did find a workaround for this problem. If I create a different View for each list length (i.e. a View for a box with 4 items, another View for a box with 3 items, another for a box with 2 items, etc) and inflate the appropriate View for each item in the list (according to its contents size), the dynamic list displays & scrolls perfectly. That works for me in this situation, as there are only 5 different permutations. However, it would be nice to figure out what the problem is, for cases when there are more permutations.